How to rename Ethernert0 card adapter in Powershell?
On Windows server 2016, i tred to:
Rename-NetAdapter -Name "Ethernet0" -NewName "Prive 172.16.255.252/16"

But nothing has changed. My adapter is still called Ethernet0.

Was there any message that appeared? Did you also try using an account with Administrator permission?

Make sure you reboot after making change.

I found the answer. yes I use powershell in Admin.
On the other hand, it is when configuring the card in static IP that the error message comes with:
New-NetIPAddress : Inconsistent parameters PolicyStore PersistentStore and Dhcp Enabled

Get-NetAdapter | Rename-NetAdapter -NewName $NewNetAdapterName

i got it

Get-NetAdapter will return an array of adapters. Is this going to try to rename them all to the same -NewName?
